# How can I put Long values in shared preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I can't put `Long` values in shared preference. When I put `String` it is working fine.

Here is the code:

```
SharedPreferences repeat_rowId = getSharedPreferences("repeat_rowId", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = repeat_rowId.edit();
editor.putLong("rowId", mRowId);// I am getting the Error in this line..
editor.putString("row_str","ABC");
editor.commit();
```

How can I use `Long` values?

Comment: It's most likely erroring because mRowId isn't of type Long - what is that variable storing when you try to do this? Or more specifically what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are not using long.

```
Long.parseLong(string);
```

use this if its a string .

Besides what does your LogCat tell...